# force user to register

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, authlogic-oid

Is it possible to require a "logged in" user to complete registration before he can continue on? This scenario happens when a user logges in via facebook or some other oauth/open id provider and the session does not provide all the requires registation data.

Here is my application controller and I am tryint this require_registration method but it somehow ends up in an infinite loop not sure what's going on.

http://pastie.org/1185477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the `before_filter` from running on the `UsersController#edit` action which the `before_filter` redirects to.

```
class UsersController
  skip_before_filter :require_registration, :only => :edit

  # ...
end
```